# Update Clock element every second in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a Clock class component which holds a date attribute inside the state of the class. The thing is, I want it to update every second using the `setState({})` method. This is what I'm trying:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()};
  }
  updateClock() {
    setInterval(this.setState({date: new   Date().toLocaleTimeString()}), 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date}.</h2>
        {this.updateClock()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

Any ideas ?
This is what I get in the console

```
bundle.js:14420 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
    at invariant (bundle.js:12885)
    at scheduleWorkImpl (bundle.js:27206)
    at scheduleWork (bundle.js:27163)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (bundle.js:21725)
    at Clock.Component.setState (bundle.js:13204)
    at Clock.updateClock (bundle.js:113)
    at Clock.render (bundle.js:128)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:23470)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:23438)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:24063)
```

Comment: You can put your function `updateClock`inside `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`. Don't put in render function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it in a render, because you will run in a situation where many intervals will be running and trying to `setState` altogether. Do it once when component mounts:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()};
    this.intervalId = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateClock();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }

  updateClock() {
    setInterval(() => this.setState({date: new   Date().toLocaleTimeString()}), 1000);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
   }
}
```

Also, don't forget to stop interval when component unmounts.

Comment: Thanks, Im a complete beginner with React

Answer (score 0):

Trigger `updateClock` in componentDidMount